# Find Sin Function from points?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I have these points and I need to find the sine function can anyone please show me how to do this step by step? Or just give me pointers on where to start and what the equation actually is?

(0,2.8) (2.4, 3.3) (6.2, 2.9) (8.6 2.7) (9.9, 2.85)

Comment: Perhaps the connection between the given points and "the sine function" you "need to find" is clear to you, but it is a matter of guesswork for us Readers.  I suggest you compare this to worked exercises in your textbook for more context.

Comment: I am using a water bottles curves to calculate the area under the sin curve. I'm honestly have no clue how to find the sin function. @peter

Comment: To me the sine curve is simply $y = \sin x$.  Apparently it has a different meaning in your problem.  To calculate "area under [a] curve" will be a standard calculus exercise once a simple formula can be found, so perhaps you are thinking about a more general function, like $y = a \sin bx + c$, to fit the data points?

Comment: Is that a homework / assignment question? If so, can you show the entire question? A point (0, 2.8) seems funny as $|sin(x)|<=1$ so not sure what 2.8 is doing there?

Answer (score 0):

The figure below shows the result of fitting with the function $y = a_0+ a_1\sin(\omega x) + a_2\cos(\omega x)$

Of course, this result can be written on the form $y = a_0+ a_3\sin(\omega x + \phi) $

[image]